# How do I randomly sort a list into two lists

Tags: objective-c, random

I have an array and I want to randomly put items in the array into two list with the same size I'm thinking of putting the items into two arrays but not sure if this is the best idea. Besides putting it in array how do I write the for stament or while loop to get all object from the array and put it in two arrays or lists.

**edit**

I would like there divide the main list in two lists. With halve the items in the one list and the other halve in the other list and I would like the selection to be random

Comment: Hey check my Answer for even number of elements in your original array. I coded for you and checked its woking as per your question.

Comment: HEy check the answer now complete one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:originalArray copyItems:TRUE];

NSMutableArray *list1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *list2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
while(temp.count > 0){

    int index1 = arc4random_uniform(temp.count);
    [list1 addObject:[temp objectAtIndex:index1]];
    [temp removeObjectAtIndex:index1];

    if(temp.count != 0){
      int index2 = arc4random_uniform(temp.count);
      [list2 addObject:[temp objectAtIndex:index2]];
      [temp removeObjectAtIndex:index2];
    }
}
```

now you will be left with 2 arrays (list1 and list2), with the contents split randomly over the 2 arrays

hopefully I interpreted your question correctly, havnt tested the code at all, should work in theory

Comment: Why 2 pointers temp1,temp2? Both point to the same original array.

Comment: right, those temps are meant to be copies of the original array

Comment: Great answer. I wasn't clear enough. See m updated answer for more.

Comment: ah, ive changed my answer to do that. will handle odd number of elements too

Comment: Thanks. I Just change objectAt to objectAtIndex and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your original array has even number of Elemnets:

```
NSMutableArray *list1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *list2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *originalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ssjsf1",@"ssjsf2",@"ssj3sf",@"ssj4sf",@"ss5jsf",@"ssj6sf",@"ssj7sf",@"ssj8sf",@"ssj9sf",@"s10sjsf",@"ss11jsf",@"ss12jsf",@"ss12jsf",@"ss12jsf",nil];
NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int i =0;
for (i = 0; [temp count] < [originalArray count] ; i++){
    int r = arc4random_uniform([originalArray count]);
    if(!([temp containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:r]]))
    {
        [temp addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:r]];
        [list1 addObject:[originalArray objectAtIndex:r]];
         if([originalArray count] % 2 == 0)
        {
            if([list1 count] > ([originalArray count]/2) )
            {
                [list1 removeObjectAtIndex:r];
                [temp removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:r]];
            }
        }
        if([originalArray count] % 2 != 0)
            if([list1 count] > ([originalArray count]/2 + 1) )
            {
                [list1 removeObjectAtIndex:r];
                [temp removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:r]];
            }
    }
    r = arc4random_uniform([originalArray count]);
    if(!([temp containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:r]]))
    {
        [temp addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:r]];
        [list2 addObject:[originalArray objectAtIndex:r]];

       if([originalArray count] % 2 == 0)
        {
            if([list2 count] > ([originalArray count]/2) )
            {
                [list1 removeObjectAtIndex:r];
                [temp removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:r]];
            }
        }
        if([originalArray count] % 2 != 0)
            if([list2 count] > ([originalArray count]/2) )
            {
                [list2 removeObjectAtIndex:r];
                [temp removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:r]];
            }
    }
}


 NSLog(@"List1 -- %@ \n List 2 --- %@",list1, list2);
```

May this will help you.

Comment: This is exactly what I want but I need it to also to take odd numbers where one list has one more item than another.

Comment: Hey edited the answer for odd counts also. i have checked this its working for both now.